# Query returning hex string rather than expected alphanumeric text; RE: mysql8+ default option --binary-as-hex

Tags: mysql

This works as expected on one machine:

```
mysql> SELECT `LengthSHOULD` FROM `LengthAndGrowing` WHERE `LenTmpPltzPerKEY`='InCompletedsLengthCheck_0';
+--------------+
| LengthSHOULD |
+--------------+
| A,B,C,D      |
+--------------+
```

but on a different computer the same code is giving me this:

```
mysql> SELECT `LengthSHOULD` FROM `LengthAndGrowing` WHERE `LenTmpPltzPerKEY`='InCompletedsLengthCheck_0';
+----------------------------+
| LengthSHOULD               |
+----------------------------+
| 0x412C422C432C44           |
+----------------------------+
```

0x41 2C 42 2C 43 2C 44   ||||  Hunh :  0x    41 2C 42 2C 43 2C 44
?        ,     ,     ,

I have gotten this far... asking mysql about what it is using internally:

```
mysql> SELECT 
    ->    column_name, 
    ->    character_set_name, 
    ->    collation_name 
    -> FROM information_schema.columns 
    -> WHERE table_name = 'LengthAndGrowing';
+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| COLUMN_NAME      | CHARACTER_SET_NAME | COLLATION_NAME     |
+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| LenTmpPltzPerKEY | utf8mb4            | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
| LengthSHOULD     | NULL               | NULL               |
| GrowingPains     | utf8mb4            | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
| AccordianString  | NULL               | NULL               |
| TimePLEASE       | utf8mb4            | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

How should I proceed to unsnarl this?

From the hint in the answer from dcolazin, yep, it was the option
--skip-binary-as-hex.

So apparently mysql 8.x+; things were made such that by default in for instance a bash shell and in the mysql running there, binary data returned by queries just gets splashed on the screen in hex.

I wound up creating under dir ~/ a new .my.cnf file and under group
[mysql] and [mysqld] and for good measure [server-client] adding the
option
skip-binary-as-hex
Useful resource: the SECTION "Option File Syntax" at MySQL Docs:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html#option-file-order

```
[mysql]
skip-binary-as-hex

[mysqld]
skip-binary-as-hex

[server-client]
skip-binary-as-hex
```

systemctl restart mysqld

mysql -u thisdelinquentuser -p

and get nice data again.

DBAABA,DBAABB,DBAABC,DBAABD,
DBAACA,DBAACB,DBAACC,DBAACD,
DBAADA,DBAADB,DBAADC,DBAADD,

Answer (score 0):

`0x412C422C432C44` is exactly the hexadecimal representation of `A,B,C,D` and you might try to use the `UNHEX()` function. Anyway, it is probably the option [`--binary-as-hex`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_binary-as-hex).